# Need way to Vent Heat out of Vaulted Ceiling in top floor Condo in Colorado

Tags: attic, heat, venting

I live in a top floor condo with a vaulted ceiling. The high vertical wall of the vaulted ceiling backs onto an attic area accessed from outside the condo.
There are NO vents and 2 poorly working small windows in the condo.

The heat build up is massive with no way to get it out or to get the outside cool night air in.

- Window fans have not worked.
- The 2 small wall ACs can not bring it down below 80 degrees on a cool day working 24/7; now utility service usage restrictions, limiting usage during the hottest hours and the amount of usage, will prevent using the ACs long enough to make any difference!

The attic area is too small for the large QuietCool type ducted vents and the cost is too high for this low-income senior.

**Are there "through-the-wall exhaust fans with dampers"** that can be put into the high ceiling area (venting into the attic) **that will pull enough air** from at least one small window to exchange the heat for the outside cool in the evenings?

An electrical control switch would have to be put into the lower condo area so it could be turned on and off, maybe with a timer.
Is this possible?
This is the high area that I need to vent the heat out of. It controls most of my 735 sq.ft. home:
[image: High Vertical Wall in living area]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It ONLY identifies and asks about ONE issue!   ????  The Question is in the Title.  The details are in the body.  I'm not sure what you are asking.  I thought I did exactly what you asked for....  Maybe being a female in my 70s with no experience doing this is the real problem?

Comment: I've added some Formatting to make this Readable and removed the Randomly capitalized Words as they Made no sense.

Comment: A picture always helps.  Everyone who reads this question is probably going to visualize what you have slightly differently.

Comment: "Now restrictions will prevent that" ... could you explain that?

Comment: if you have two windows you can vent your space well with quality window fans. One pulls in, one pushes out.

Comment: Thank you "FreeMan" for the help!  "CGCampbell", I added explanation above.

Comment: "dandavis" - I tried that previously with only some help.  One window is in danger of "blowing out" and is too dangerous to put a fan in. I'm no longer stronger enough to open or close the windows or put fans in and out of them.   That's why I'm trying to find another affordable way to vent the heat. Thank you.

Comment: One problem with venting into the attic is the wall between your condo and the attic may be required to be a firewall. Another problem is if the attic doesn't have a good exhaust fan of its own then adding the heat from your condo may be too much. If it was a single family home then fan to attic plus exhaust fan in attic would be great. Have you checked with other condo owners to see what they have done?

Comment: I have an unanswered question to management. The attic area in question is "over my unit". Other attic areas branch off to the south and west and are smaller (I've never looked into them and only saw part of mine about 10 years ago).  My area has 4 of the "flat looking vents" and 1 tall pipe-like vent that once was connected to a kitchen vent that was taken out before I moved in. Electrical work has been done in the past in the attic for my unit.

Comment: Wouldn't the air pressure from the Vent (or vents) force the hot air out the roof vents while pulling cooler air from my windows into the attic?

Comment: You can place a large (probably round) duct against the ceiling, as high as it will go, place vents in the side of the duct, and use some sort of fan to pull the air out and send it to an exhaust vent or some such.

Comment: That might require "roof work" which I do not have access to.  The large "quietcool type exhaust fans with short ducting, use a fan to" only vent into the attic, letting the passive attic vents take the hot air out the roof. I was hoping to find a "smaller, less expensive" way to do the same thing; possibly using vertical exhaust vents with good dampers that have no ducting and just pull the air into the attic.

Comment: The ceiling has no space and is sloped down, away from the attic. The Vertical Wall backing onto the attic is the only good possibility.

Comment: And random Caps are Back. that's really Distracting and hard To read When random Words are Capitalized for no good Reason.

Comment: @FreeMan - ? - I changed "1 story" to "top floor" trying to make it clearer.  The other caps have been there, such as "Vertical Wall" because I was trying to emphasize that that is the wall I need to put a vent in. I did not change anything else. I'm sorry... I don't know what you are pointing to.  I can try to make more changes.  Will it matter? No one seems interested.  I hope you have a good day.

Comment: Randomly capitalized words ("now Utility Service Usage restrictions", "exhaust Fans with dampers") are a distraction and incorrect usage. Capitalize the first word of a sentence and proper nouns, possibly every word in a headline. Of course, "everyone's doing it these days", but that hardly makes it right. You've had several people ask clarifying questions, you seem to be providing answers. I would expect someone helps you come up with an answer sooner rather than later.

Comment: @FreeMan - thank you for you help. I do need to learn to communicate better and appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: It's not just you, BLR. Random caps, no caps at all, misplaced punctuation, no punctuation at all... these are all symptoms of modern American writing (probably other places in the world, too). Thanks for taking it the right way. _Sorry, grammar and punctuation are a pet peeve of mine - my mom has an English degree and both of my parents were **very** picky about it._

Comment: @FreeMan - It's ok.  I started life autistic and have spent a long lifetime learning. Now, I understand and can use the correct words; yet, still don't know how to organize and present them in a way that fully communicates what is needed. Thank you.